# Constant is used before being initialized for JSON function | Swift

Tags: ios, swift

**I would like to decode JSON and use the results to determine what to do in a conditional**

**The following is the JSON function:**

```
var checkStructure = [Structure1]()

     func checkingJSON() {
             guard let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example"),
                 let value = name.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
                 else { return }

             var request = URLRequest(url: url)
             request.httpMethod = "POST"
             request.httpBody = "name=\(value)&name2=\(example1)".data(using: .utf8)

             URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
                 guard let data = data else { return }
                 do {
                     self.checkStructure = try JSONDecoder().decode([Structure1].self,from:data)
                     DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     }
                 }
                 catch {
                     print(error)
                 }

                 }.resume()

         }
```

**The following is how I decode it:**

```
struct Structure1: Codable {
    var name, NUM1 : String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case NUM1 = "NUM1"
    }
}
```

**And when bar button item is pressed, the following conditional should execute:**

```
let structureValue: Structure1

 if let num = Int(structureValue.NUM1), num < 1 {

       let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Del1") as! TableViewController1
       let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
       self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

  } else {

      let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Del2") as! TableViewController2
      let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
      self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

      }
```

**But I get the following error message for the line let structureValue:**

```
if let num = Int(structureValue.NUM1), num < 1 {
```

> Constant 'structureValue' used before being initialized

Comment: Where is structureValue initialized? The conditional should execute after structureValue initialized.

Comment: How can I initialize it?

Comment: self.structureValue = try JSONDecoder().decode([Structure1].self,from:data)